# Auto-start chrome home-screen app (open to rooting options)

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I have a Chrome Home-screen app on my Pixel-C tablet (where I have clicked 'Add to Home Screen' from Chrome Android).

Is it possible to root the Android tablet so that it automatically runs this web app in full screen mode on start-up without any user interaction being necessary? Very much like a Kiosk app, where the user should only be able to interact with the app itself (not the OS).

So far, I have tried using the Android Auto Start app, although it cannot detect Chrome Home-screen apps. My current setup is using the 'Immersive Mode' app to remove the navigation and status bar controls and then opening the kiosk style app manually.

I am open to any suggestions -- including rooting the device, which is probably necessary given the amount of control required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to crate a [custom launcher](https://github.com/arnabc/simplelauncher)(Google "creating android custom launcher" for more such examples). Launcher is the home screen interface which user interacts to. In your custom launcher, you can restrict what app icons to show and what not to. You can choose this to be your only app and open it on boot and even relaunch when tried to exit.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Most automation apps (and 'Auto Start') do not detect my Chrome web-app that's been added to the Home screen. Do you think I will be able to access it from the Package Manager in order to launch it from a custom launcher? Just trying to understand why these other apps can't see it...

Comment: Yes. You can open with custom launcher. We have out own version of Custom launcher though which we are able to launch. I'm not sure what app you tried to auto launch. If it has provision to open a URL, try opening the start URL of your PWA(like https://example.com/myapp/") and Android will detect there is a PWA installed for this URL and will launch your app. Accept the answer if it solves your question.

Comment: Great, this is all working well! One last thing, if you don't mind -- Chrome opens the URL in the Chome app (in a tab) but takes about 5 seconds to realise there is a PWA installed to Home, and then switches, which is quite a clunky UX. Is there any way to improve this? Cheers.

Comment: That part is fully handled by browser and the we can’t do anything about it. I don’t see the time lag though. Not sure why in your case. All you can try is to make sure you have latest of Chrome and Android if possible. Accept the answer if it solves ur question.